# Form submit button not working Rails 6 on validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure this out. With no validations in the model the form submits, saves, and posts notice just fine. If I create any validation in the model like "validates_presence_of :first_name" and I leave that first_name field blank, then when I click the form submit button the button just freezes and I can't press it again after correcting the field. And the page does not post any errors either as the page basically freezes.

Here's my code:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
      if @message.save
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:notice] = "We have received your message and will be in touch soon!"
      else
        render :new
        flash.now[:alert] = "Error! Could not send message, all fields must be filled out properly"
      end
  end
  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :body)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
  <%= form_with(model: @message, local: true) do |f| %>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.submit 'Send', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

message.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: messages
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  body       :text
#  email      :string
#  first_name :string
#  last_name  :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
class Message < ApplicationRecord

  validates_presence_of :first_name

end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your page is freezing. But as for the rendering the flash message, that is not done automatically. You have to render it inside your views, probably application layout if you have many errors to render for different actions. This is an example:

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
  <div>
    <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I like the way it is explained [here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/11/rails-flash-messages/)